# как правильно организовать поиск по сайту? Laravel?

Tags: laravel

```
чтобы получить страницу и на ней ссылки на страницы где есть совпадения
к примеру есть таблицы:
posts
pages
news

и ссылки на них 
вида

http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/helloworld //Post
http://127.0.0.1:8000/about  //Page
http://127.0.0.1:8000/news/156  //News

Page::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->query . '%')->get();
News::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->query . '%')->get();
Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->query . '%')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте Laravel Scout - https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/scout

Laravel Scout предоставляет простое решение на основе драйверов для добавления полнотекстового поиска